# HTML in Favorite and Ignored Tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, xss

If you add `"'><h1>` to either Favorite Tags or Ignored Tags on the home page, it'll insert the HTML into the page and break the page layout. Also, after refreshing the page, some new tags will be added: classpost-tag, titleshow, questions etc.

Though, it isn't critical, but an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: That's a cool bug.

Answer (score 3):

Hehe, nice one. Although tagging it [xss](/questions/tagged/xss) is somewhat of a stretch; I don't see a way for a third party to exploit this :)

Anyhow, this will be fixed in the next build; we already had some client-side tag validation code, it just wasn't used in this situation.