# Cannot add ignored tag with wildcards anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags, wildcards

Everytime I try add it, it simply strips the wildcard character.

This has only been happening since today. (27 jan 2011)

I only use StackOverflow, not sure if present on other sites.

Comment: I still have a few in action which when clicked still work as intended. But you can't add them any more. Tested on SF and scifi.SE.

Comment: @Kev: Yes, the same, existing ones work, new ones dont get added correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault; I broke that yesterday when fixing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76536/html-in-favorite-and-ignored-tags). It works again now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing (not for breaking :p)