# Tags: advanced favourite/ignored sets

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

I have 10 favourite tags and 62 ignored. Half the ignored are variations of for instance "visual-studio":

- [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)
- [visual-studio-2003](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2003)
- [visual-studio-2005](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2005)
- [visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008)
- [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010)

Or ".net":

- [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
- [.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/.net-mvc)
- [.net-2003](/questions/tagged/.net-2003)
- [.net-2005](/questions/tagged/.net-2005)

Has there been a request to add more advanced filtering, for example using regular expressions (`delphi*`, `spring*` etc.)?

Comment: Also, does it make sense to have server-side filtering of questions on homepage rather than leaving it to the browser (jscript), or it requires more CPU/memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already possible see [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/):

However there is a [temporary bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76655/cannot-add-ignored-tag-with-wildcards-anymore) that makes it unavailable, I believe it's going back in some time

Comment: That bug is fixed now.